# Compiler optimisation - statement rearrangement algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, memory, compiler-optimization

So I'm interested of any approaches for compilers to rearrange specific statements in order to allow better memory allocation, e.g. register assignment. Thus in some cases it could be possible to evaluate a statement earlier, such that we can reuse the intermediate register. Consider:

```
input(a1,a2,a3)
b = f1(a1,a2);
c = f2(b,a3);
d = f3(b,a1,a2);
k = f4(c,1);
l = f5(d,a3);
r = k + l + b + c;
```

Here the compiler will use 4 "registers" - 1)b,2)c,3)d and l,4)k and r will be any of the previous.
Instead this could be more efficient in terms of register allocation if we do something like this:

```
input(a1,a2,a3)
b = f1(a1,a2);
c = f2(b,a3);
r = b + c + f4(c,1);
c = f3(b,a1,a2);
r += f5(c,a3);
```

Where we can use 3 registers.

What I'm looking for is given a compute graph, where I have all the variable dependencies, to generate a better optimised code for registers. The question is is there any algorithmic way of doing this?

PS: Note the example might not be the best, but couldn't think of anything else simple.

Comment: This is (at least) a semester-long course at the graduate level.  But look up "register coloring".

Comment: I know (at least a bit) about register colouring, but that is something that needs the time dependency graph (NO?), which comes from in what order is written each statement. Might be wrong, but isn't this something before the registry coloring?

Comment: Like I said, it's a semester-long course.  The term "node numbering" comes to mind, but it's been about 15 years since I mucked in the stuff, and my memory is not well-known for it's incredible accuracy and persistence.

Comment: Could you suggest a book maybe or some resource I can dig in to?

Comment: A good place to start is with the dragon book.